# Configurar PHP INI para carregar arquivo PHP default

Tags: php

Como configurar o php.ini para carregar um arquivo PHP que contém algumas funções genérica onde uso em todos os projetos do meu root?

Li algo sobre `include_path`, porém não entendi e acredito que não suprime o que eu necessito!

Comment: Eu não sei se dá, nunca fui atrás disso porque não é uma boa ideia. Eu nem perderia meu tempo em procurar.

Comment: Para o que eu quero fazer seria ótimo! Tenho um vários projetos interligados em um root, e dentro desse root tenho arquivo de configurações. Porém para eu ter acesso a essas configurações eu necessito chamar essa função em todos os projetos sem ficar dando include em arquivos..

Comment: Você pensa que seria ótimo, mas não sabe onde está se metendo.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei porque precisas disso, mas aí vai:

- Abra o arquivo PHP.ini, e busque por "include_path":
- Altere o seu valor:

> include_path = "/var/meus_includes"

Nota que podes incluir mais de um directorio:

> include_path = "/var/inc1:/var/inc2:/var/inc3"

- Por último, reinicia o servidor:

> sudo service apache2 restart